# How do I add a style element to a div and remove it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a margin-left css style to a div element when an event is triggered by the user clicking a button, and then remove it when the user clicks the button again.

This is the div element:

```
<div id="container" class="content">
```

Javascript should change it to:

```
<div id="container" class="content" style="margin-left:354px">
```

Ideally using an animation so it appears to slide left rather than jump.

Comment: Pure javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the event listener:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
cont.style.marginLeft = cont.style.marginLeft === "354px" ? "auto" "354px";
```

This doesn't animate it. You may consider using CSS for that:

```
#container {
    transition: margin-left ease 500ms;
}
```

But if you want to support older browsers and IE9, go for soyuka's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/animate) before posting such a question...

```
$('.content').animate({'margin-left':'354px'}, 1000); 
//where 1000 is the animation time in ms
```

To roll back :

```
$('.content').animate({'margin-left':'auto'}); //or your previous value
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution Ive just dropped into JSBin: http://jsbin.com/oyemen/1/edit

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`jQuery.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) along with the `margin-left` css attribute. The second parameter of `animate` is the duration (in milliseconds). There are a bunch of other settings to allow finer control of the animation (eg, easing-in or -out).

```
$('#container').animate({'margin-left':'354px'},3000);
```

and to move it back the opposite

```
$('#container').animate({'margin-left':'0px'},3000);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xdpCs/1/

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Very little experience so live example helped me

Comment: @Jamiec Beats me. Even soyuka's answer got a downvote, and both are perfectly good.